# Store data from Plotly Dash to an external object

Tags: python-3.x, callback, plotly, plotly-dash

I have stored `df` in JSON format in `dcc.Store(id='store-csv')`. I want to pull out the JSON object and assign it to an external `new_df` (NOT within dash). How do I extract it from `dcc.Store(id='store-csv')`?

For example :

```
@app.callback(
        Output('store-csv', 'data'),
        Input('csv-input', 'value'))

def store_csv(csv_input):
        df = pd.DataFrame(some_df)
        return df.to_json(orient='split')

new_df = store_csv(csv_input) # Issue here. How to I store df (within dash) to new_df (not within dash)?
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you want to do exactly, but one option could be to use some sort of mutable reference type like an object or a dictionary to store the most up-to-date value of `csv_input`.

Simplified example:

```
data = {"value": ""}

@app.callback(Output("store", "data"), Input("input", "value"))
def store_csv(input_value):
    data["value"] = input_value # update data["value"]
    return input_value

# Use data["value"] somewhere
```

Most of the time you don't need to do this though, because you could just share data between different callbacks using `Input` or `State` values.